# Explaining \begin{tabularx}{*} commands to align text and images in a table

Tags: tables, graphics, vertical-alignment, tabularx, texmaker

I am trying to vertically align my text and images in a table. I have seen several feeds where this question is addressed, however I am still battling to understand how the **\tabularx{}{}** command is used and means. In particular the second portion of the bracket where you specify **m{},p{},b{}** etc.

In my case I have used **{\textwidth}{c *{2}{Y}}** - got this from another answer posted - not sure exactly what it means...

Attached is my code and image of the table I am creating:

```
\begin{table}[H]
 \caption{Classification}
 \label{tbl:Longwall systems}
 \footnotesize
 \centering 

    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{c *{2}{Y}}
     \toprule 
      Classifications & Description \\ 
     \midrule
     \raisebox{-\totalheight}{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth, height=30mm]{./Figures/Longwall single entry retreating}} & Single entry advancing\\
      \midrule

      {\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth, height=30mm]{./Figures/Longwall single entry retreating}} & Single entry retreating\\
      \midrule
      \end{tabularx}

\end{table}
```

I would simply just like to vertically align both the text and images to center in the table.

Will greatly appreciate the assistance. Thanks
(Note I am still new to latex :))
[image]

Comment: How is the `Y` column type defined?

Comment: @Mat the `m` can be defined directly as `m{4in}` or in relative terms `m{0.4\textwidth}` or wit relation to the linewidth-- combining the `m` vertical centering with `c` horizontal centering is done by  `\centering\arraybackslash}m{2in}`

Comment: @js bibra - thanks : )

Comment: please accept and upvote the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not knowing whaht the `Y` column type is, I replaced it with `X`. You can either use  `\raisebox{-0.5\totalheight}{…}` or load the `adjustbox` package with option `export`  and use `\includegraphics[valign=c]`.`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo, export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{float, tabularx, booktabs, caption}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{table}{4}
\begin{table}[H]
 \caption{Classification}
 \label{tbl:Longwall systems}
 \footnotesize
 \centering

    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{c *{2}{X}}
     \toprule
      Classifications & Description \\
     \midrule
     \raisebox{-0.5\totalheight}{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth, height=30mm]{./Figures/Longwall single entry retreating}} & Single entry advancing\\
      \midrule

      {\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth, height=30mm, valign=c]{./Figures/Longwall single entry retreating}} & Single entry retreating\\
      \midrule
      \end{tabularx}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I am not sure what the X and Y column types mean. But your code also seemed to work equally good

Comment: In a `tabularx{\textwidth}` environment, `X` columns are `p{...}` columns, the width thereof is the remaining width available on the line, after the other column types have been placed, equally shared by the X columns. I suppose the `Y` column type is some custom type, based on the `X`  type.

Comment: Also the **valign** code in `\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth, height=30mm, valign=c` how does that work? Lets say if I were to have 3 images instead of 2, would I simply add the valign in the last portion of code of the  `\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth, height=30mm, valign=c` and will all the images be aligned?

Comment: This key (which is defined by `adjustbox`)  aligns the vertical centre of the image with the current base line, so yes, you should add it to each `\includegraphics`.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
 \documentclass{article}
% \usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
            \begin{table}
 \caption{Classification}
 \label{tbl:Longwall systems}
 \footnotesize
 \centering 

    \begin{tabular}{m{0.4\linewidth}m{0.5\linewidth}}
     \toprule 
      Classifications & Description \\ 
     \midrule
     {\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth, height=30mm]{example-image}} & Single entry advancing\\
      \midrule
      {\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth, height=30mm]{example-image}} & Single entry retreating\\
      \midrule
      \end{tabular}

\end{table}   
\end{document}
```

**EDIT**
To centre the headings also -- not done before

[image]

```
\begin{tabular}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2in}>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{4in}}
 \toprule 
  Classifications & Description \\ 
 \midrule
 {\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image}} & Single entry advancing\\
  \midrule
  {\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image}} & Single entry retreating\\
  \midrule
  \end{tabular}
```

Comment: 10000!!! likes. Thanks.